# When importing shapefile gives an error "No dataset found at path"

Tags: shapefile, geopandas, import

I'm trying to follow [this](https://geohackweek.github.io/vector/04-geopandas-intro/) tutorial to GeoPandas and am trying to import the "oceans.shp" file, which I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Training-Data/tree/master/training_manual_data/world) (together with the `.dbf`, `.prj`, `qpj`, and `.shx` files),

When running the code

```
oceans = gpd.read_file('[...]\oceans.shp')
```

I get the error

```
FionaValueError: No dataset found at path '[...]\oceans.shp' using drivers: *
```

What am I doing wrong - can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. Yes, I'm using the entire path - that's just for better readability. :)

Comment: What other files do you have in the same directory? (there should at least be two other files with the same name but different extensions `.shx` and `.dbf` in the same directory).

Comment: If I would follow that tutorial I would first try the syntax literally without changing anything else but the data_pth variable to point where ever your data are `oceans = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(data_pth, "oceans.shp"))`.

Comment: @user30184 Yep, that's what I'm doing/ trying to do - then I'm encountering that error.

Comment: @joris In the directory, there are `ocean.dbf`, `.prj`, `.qpj`, `.shp`, `.shx`.

Comment: Are you able to share the data?

Comment: Of course. The data is available here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qvahth56kpsoddk/AABsafHDMLPg2p0eCjebvb8Ia?dl=0

Comment: Try putting a lowercase r in front of the first quotation mark.  Sometimes your path will have some letters following a backslash that python reads as an escape character (like \n for newline).  So oceans = gpd.read_file(r'[...]\oceans.shp') should solve that.

Comment: There is probably a problem with the Fiona build you have. Check [this](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/199).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you wrote the path properly?

If the file is in the same directory than the script, do this:

```
import os

oceans = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'oceans.shp')
```

Using `os` assures you that you won't have conflicts of paths when switching from windows to linux.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion - the error persists, however. :(

Comment: Do you use linux? Can you post the results of `ls ./`? (directory where the file and the script is)

Comment: No, it's Windows 10...

Comment: For that path to work the wd has to be set and the shapefile needs to be in it

Comment: If you use windows then the slashes are wrong in the path in your code. Windows uses backslashes \, as shown in BERA's comment to your question

Comment: @BERA, yes, I did - have done that but still have the problem.

Comment: @ImanolUr, true - I used backslashes in the actual code then leading to the problem (using slashes would've thrown a different error) - but I fixed it in the question.
The problem is still standing though. :(
Any ideas?

Comment: If the file is in the same directory than the script, you can also try to not give the full path, and just write ('oceans.shp'). Another possibility, are the files in another hard-drive/partition?

Comment: No, forward slashes are valid in Windows.